# Automatic sending of notification mails to users - information stored in mongodb

Tags: php, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, cron

I am working on a website where you (easily spoken) answer questions. After answering something, the question disappears and comes back later for another answer from the same user (time of reappearing is different each time).

All my data is stored in a mongodb and I used node.js and angular to build the website.

I want to create a server job (cron job?!) that e.g. every 12 hours runs automatically, checks in the database if there are questions available for the users and then sends a notification email do the address(es) stored in mongodb.

What is the best way of doing it?

Hope someone can help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using mailJet to send emails from my Node.js server - fairly flexible and reliable (other options mailgun, mailchimp, ...). See the code here:

https://github.com/cyrillef/extract-view.and.data.api/blob/master/server/sendMail.js

You can also use the standard mail transport API. i.e nodemailer at https://nodemailer.com/

Comment: Thanks, but can it run automatically via cron-job? The most important is that the mail sending happens automatically.